# Grails and multiple databases (one per host)?

Tags: grails

Is there a way (in Grails) to change the 'primary' database while the application is running, but before any domain objects have been instantiated?  I'm trying to set up an app where each customer has their own database, but don't want to have to run a separate Java interpreter for every single customer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out : 
http://www.leebutts.com/2008/07/switchable-grails-datasource.html